# dojo crashes ie6 when using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo

I'm having issues with a application that I am writing that uses Dojo and Zend Framework.  The issue only effects Internet Explorer 6, other versions of IE, ff, chrome and safari work fine with no issues.

When IE6 lands on the login page it crashes with the send details to microsoft dialog box.  The login script uses dojo to provide some validation for the users to ensure that their passwords are formatted correctly etc.

I've seen on some forums that addOnLoad() function call in dojo could be the cause and a window.setTimeout() would help. http://www.dojotoolkit.org/forum/dojo-core-dojo-0-9/dojo-core-support/dom-manipulation-addonload-crashes-ie6

The problem I have is how to manipulate the dojo header that we have in the layout.phtml in the application.  We currently have in the file this code in the header.

```
<?php
        $this->dojo()->setLocalPath($this->baseUrl().'/javascript/dojo/dojo.js');
        $this->dojo()->addStylesheetModule('dijit.themes.tundra');
        echo $this->dojo();

?>
```

This produces the following in the html.

```
 
dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    dojo.forEach(zendDijits, function(info) {
        var n = dojo.byId(info.id);
        if (null != n) {
            dojo.attr(n, dojo.mixin({ id: info.id }, info.params));
        }
    });
    dojo.parser.parse();
});
var zendDijits = [{"id":"username","params":{"regExp":"[a-z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,4})$","invalidMessage":"Please enter a valid email address","trim":"true","required":"true","dojoType":"dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"}},{"id":"password1","params":{"trim":"true","lowercase":"true","regExp":"^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$","invalidMessage":"Invalid Password.  Password must be at least 6 alphanumeric characters","required":"true","dojoType":"dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"}},{"id":"submit","params":{"label":"Login","dojoType":"dijit.form.Button"}}];
```

How can I change this to try and add the fixes mentioned in the link, or is there another way to write this without IE6 crashing all the time??  I would prefer to fix this than remove all the client validation, just in case the client is using IE6.

thanks...

Comment: The code above looks fine.  Is there anything else on the page that might be the culprit?  

I've got pretty much the same thing (not via Zend though) running on IE6 without any problems.

Comment: Not really all I have are 2 text boxes that use a few regex to check that the username is an email address and that the password matches the password requirements, plus a login button.  Other than that there are no other dojo components.

Comment: Weird.  I just set up this page http://jsbin.com/utami3 and it works fine in my version of IE6.  What version of dojo does Zend use?

Comment: I'm using the latest library from dojotoolkit.org 1.3.1.  It is very strange, but breaks on all the test machines that we have running ie6. Other browsers work fine no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Can you reduce it down until you find what is crashing IE6? Save off your output as static html, confirm it still crashes IE and start removing code. Take that addOnLoad out altogether - does it still crash? if not, take out the forEach, and so on. Start removing elements from zendDijits array - is there one in particular that causes the trouble?

Is this a stock IE6? Any plugins/addons?

Your php there should be producing a script element to pull dojo.js. You've got soemthing wierd going on - that Zend code is known to work so we need *all* the information if you want to solve this.